# Send Audio by Email

Tags: ios, audio, share

How could I get the audio from phone and get it to share via email?
Will it available?
Can we share it simply like music at application?

Comment: Do you want audio from the iPod or your bundle?

Answer (score 2):

Your question could have been better, you should show what you've tried, your specific problem, your actual results and your expected result.

Having said that, this sounded like a nice challenge.. so the answer follows.

I'm not sure if you wanted to get the music from the iPod or the app bundle so I implemented the iPod version as (in my opinion), it's more complex.

## SSCCE:

### main.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

### AppDelegate.h

```
@import UIKit;
@import MessageUI;
@import MediaPlayer;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

### AppDelegate.m

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    _window.rootViewController = controller;

    MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeAny];
    mediaPicker.delegate = self;
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
    mediaPicker.prompt = @"Select songs to play";
    [_window.rootViewController presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:^{
    }];

    return YES;
}


-(void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Result:%d", result);
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


-(void) mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
    [mediaPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSArray *recipents = @[@"a@b.com"];

        MFMailComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        messageController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [messageController setToRecipients:recipents];
        [messageController setMessageBody:@"Here is a music track" isHTML:NO];
        [messageController setSubject:@"Music"];

        NSURL *tmpDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() isDirectory:YES];

        for (MPMediaItem *item in mediaItemCollection.items)
        {
            NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
            AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
            NSArray *presets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:asset];
            AVAssetExportSession *session = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:asset presetName:presets[0]];
            session.outputURL = [[tmpDirURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"item"] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"m4a"];
            session.outputFileType = [session supportedFileTypes][0];
            [session exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:session.outputURL];
                [messageController addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"audio/mp4" fileName:@"musicAttachment.m4a"];
            }];
        }
        [_window.rootViewController presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:^{
        }];
    }];

}

-(void) mediaPickerDidCancel:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker
{

}

@end
```

Comment: Nice answer! I am trying to directly send single song when clicking on it. I tried removing `[mediaPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{   }];` but that doesn't help. I get a gray row when i select a song. Any idea how i can achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to send an email without using the mail composer?

Comment: No but i am trying to send only 1 song when i click on it, in other words i want to show the mail composer when i select the song.

Comment: Are you using this as an SSCCE at the minute? Or integrated with your own code?

Comment: I have created a simple project with uiviewcontroller and made it load  the picker directly.

Comment: Got it working by setting `mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems` to `NO` which will change `Done` button to `Cancel` button and the delegate method `mediaPicker:didPickMediaItems:` will call when a single song is selected. Thanks for your help and for the nice answer. Should be accepted.